# DateTime2 prefixed with "T"

Tags: sql-server, datetime2

When using *Tasks - Generate Scripts...* it is now generating the DateTime2 with a Prefix of "T" for the time (example 1) instead of leaving it blank (example 2). How do I remove the Prefix "T" when generating my scripts?

Example 1:
CAST(N'2017-04-18**T**00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2)

Example 2:
CAST(N'2017-04-18 00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2)

I have tried generating at a previous version of SQL i.e. 2008 or 2012 to see if it was a versioning issues which still did not work.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Are you saying the cast doesn't work, or generating it in the format you want doesn't?

Comment: FYI, the "T" version is the ISO 8601 standard datetime format.

Comment: As Dan commented per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime2)

Comment: I'm wanting to generate it in the Example 2 because when I merge my changes it now thinks I've changed all my tables, where I haven't. I know it is a standard format, but is there a way to revert it back or toggle it on and off?